# Why does the STORE button on Amazon Kindle go to the website instead of the in app store?

Tags: kindle-for-android

I have the **Android Amazon Kindle** app installed on both my **Galaxy S phone** and my **Archos 10" tablet**.

I keep the software updated so I'm sure the latest version is installed.

I am logged in with my account on both devices.

When I press the `STORE` button I go to the inprog Kindle store. But when I press the `STORE` button on the Archos it starts the web browser in stead.

Now, I have bought ebooks before from both devices and I am sure that previously, the Archos also displayed the inprog store. It's much easier to use the inprog store display than the full Amazon web site version.

**Does anyone now what could have changed this behavior ?** I looked for some setting but found none.

Comment: Was this problem present when you firstly used your device????

Comment: I have this issue too, I think it has to do with having kindle app installed on a device with several users. I don't know how to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with how intents work exactly but this looks like the browser is mistakenly set as the default app for something it shouldn't handle. Try installing [DefaultApp Reset](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pxlib.android.defaultappset&hl=en) and reset your browser as a default app. This will make sure it won't be registered as the default handler for anything at all. Then try going to the store again.

Comment: That did not work. I cleared the defaults for my Browser, then I went into my Kindle app and hit the Kindle Store button. Now it actually asked me which browser I wanna use. This is very annoying. I believe this is the same behavior on the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

I have a rooted Lenovo A1 that is experiencing the same problem.  I cannot say for certain what is causing the problem, but I don't believe that it's being rooted is the issue.  I have been able to resolve the problem temporarily by decreasing the screen resolution using an app called "LCD Resolution" which I had installed for other reasons.  When the Kindle In App store stops working, I decrease the resolution from 240 to 210.  Normally after the device reboots, the In App store in Kindle works again.  I then reset me resolution back to its previous 240 setting and all is well... for a while.  This fix is only temporary and I haven't figured out what is causing the problem.  I'm hesitant to leave the settings at 210 because it has caused problems for some of the Google Apps, like "Play Movies" not to function properly.  If I find out anymore, I'll update this post.