# Kindle on Galaxy tab 7.7 suddenly has no Kindle Store

Tags: kindle-for-android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the STORE button on Amazon Kindle go to the website instead of the in app store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21779/why-does-the-store-button-on-amazon-kindle-go-to-the-website-instead-of-the-in-a)

Usually when I click the Kindle Store button on my Kindle app I will be taken to a store inside the app. All of a sudden it doesn't work that way anymore. Now when I click the button the browser opens and I am forced to use amazon.com to shop for ebooks. What's going on?